# Symfony2 redirectToRoute without return

Tags: php, symfony

redirectToRoute has to be returned by a controller action to work. For example:

```
function testAction() {
    return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
}
```

But how is it possible to call the redirect outside the action function (from an another function)? Like:

```
function checkError() {
    $this->redirectToRoute('error');
}
```

Comment: It wouldn't make any sense to do that. `redirectToRoute` returns a `RedirectResponse` object, you have to do something with that object, in itself it's useless to have "floating" around in your method. Perhaps you can explain why you (think you) need this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

redirectToRoute() will always need to be returned because what it actually does is send a Response to the browser that triggers the redirect. If nothing is returned from a method that has a redirectToRoute() call in it, the redirect doesn't make its way back to the browser and no redirect will happen.

Answer (score 2):

Controller must return Response. There is no way (almost) to avoid it.

What you can do is use exception in your internal function(s), catch exception in controller and return response from controller. Ex.

```
function testAction() {
    try {
        checkError();
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('error');
    }
    $this->redirectToRoute('success');
}
```

Then in your `checkError()` function throw an exception.

```
function checkError() {
    throw new Exception();
}
```

This is a basic case. There are more [advanced ways to handle exceptions in Symfony2](http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2012/12/prevent-controller-execution-with-annotations-and-return-a-custom-response/) and there are [more advanced ways of throwing exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php) as well.

Comment: This function is defined inside of the parent class. I call it from more than one controller action. Isn't it a better way of checking it in each action?

Comment: Then I'd suggest to use the method from the link I've aded to my answer. By handling kernel.exception you can redirect user where needed. Extend standard exception with class that can store response. Throw that exception with desired response in your function and set it to $event->setResponse() in event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it like this:

```
public function testAction() {
    if (checkError()) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
    } else {
        // return normal response
    }
}

private function checkError() {
    //test something
    if ($error) return true; //I know I could just return $error
    return false;            //just making this clear
}
```